# How can you clone an ORM Entity and create a new record with cloned properties?

Tags: coldfusion

Reason being, there are over a 100 columns I would like to reuse and only 4 columns will be changed and then inserted as a new record. My last resort would be to load the entity I would like to clone then manually set the new entity’s properties with loaded entity.

I have tried the following.

```
<!--- load entity I would like to clone -->
<cfset mainObj= EntityLoad("myBean",{fkOtherId = 2},true)>
<!--- create new entity to save -->
<cfset newObj = EntityNew( "myBean" )>
<!--- clone entity -->
<cfset newObj = EntityMerge(mainObj)>
<cfset newObj.setFirstName(‘John’)>
<cfset newObj.setLastName(‘Smith’)>
<cfset entitySave(newObj)>
```

Solved: use

```
<cfset newObj = duplicate(mainObj)>
<cfset newObj.setId(‘’)>
<cfset newObj.setFirstName(‘John’)>
<cfset newObj.setLastName(‘Smith’)>
<cfset entitySave(newObj, true)>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

entitySave has a second argument called forceInsert. That should work here.

```
<cfset entitySave( newObj, true )>
```

Comment: Looks like you pointed me in the right direction. Not sure why it's not working. I even used ormFlush() and ormReload(). Any other suggestions?

Comment: Can you view the SQL being created by Hibernate/CF? 
And what happens if you use duplicate instead of entityMerge?